# I am trying to enter values in a MYSQL database using flask_sqlalchemy and flask but it's showing error

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am not really sure but it's showing the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Ishmeet\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 7, in 
> db = SQLAlchemy(app)
>
> File "C:\Users\Ishmeet\PycharmProjects\Flask Project\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 219, in **init**
> self.init_app(app)
>
> File "C:\Users\Ishmeet\PycharmProjects\Flask Project\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 326, in init_app
> engines[key] = self._make_engine(key, options, app)
>
> File "C:\Users\Ishmeet\PycharmProjects\Flask Project\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 614, in _make_engine
> return sa.engine_from_config(options, prefix="")
>
> File "C:\Users\Ishmeet\PycharmProjects\Flask Project\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 804, in engine_from_config
> return create_engine(url, **options)
>
> File "", line 2, in create_engine
>
> File "C:\Users\Ishmeet\PycharmProjects\Flask Project\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 283, in warned
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
>
> File "C:\Users\Ishmeet\PycharmProjects\Flask Project\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 601, in create_engine
> dbapi = dbapi_meth(**dbapi_args)
>
> File "C:\Users\Ishmeet\PycharmProjects\Flask Project\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\mysqldb.py", line 152, in import_dbapi
> return **import**("MySQLdb")
>
> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'**
> Process finished with exit code 1

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/contact'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)



class Contact_info(db.Model):
    #S.No,Phone_Number,Name
    S_No = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    Phone_Number = db.Column(db.String(12), unique=True, nullable=False)

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        '''ADD ENTRY TO THE DATABASE'''
        name = request.form.get('Name')
        phone = request.form.get('phone_number')

        entry = Contact_info(Name=name,Phone_Number=phone)
        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template('index.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```